# displaying images referenced in mysql database using react

Tags: mysql, reactjs, image

i've seen an example where one uses the map method to 'extract' images from hardcoded data (eg an array containing image paths) to display pictures on a webpage.

i'd like to do something similar except this data which is now external sits in a mysql database.

my thinking is maybe there's a way to import mysql data into an array variable to expose this data to the map method, mimicking the hardcoded scenario? just looking to see if i'm on the right track or whether i should be barking up another tree.

Comment: You could just `fetch` the results directly via MySQL's API, or you could use something like this module to help query it: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql then just do what you wish with the results in the front end

Comment: Do you have control on the backend code that is serving your React app? Because there is where you should extract the data from the database, to make it available to the frontend somehow. Usually through an HTTP API.

Comment: @Jayce444
i used a fetch-based approach to bring the data into react (in the presence of node and express).
after some experimentation, i got the desired result.
thank you both for the guidance.